# Certificate path issue

Tags: windows, iis, certificate

I have a certificate associated with a sub-domain.

The certificate is valid; when I open the certificate on a specific server and select the "Certification Path" tab I see a 3-level certificate path tree (correct).

On the server I want to install the certificate onto (to use in IIS), the certification path is broken and the get the following message:

> Windows Does Not Have Enough Information to Verify this Certificate

...after installing my EV certificate.

Why does this happen and how can I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said, I was sure that the certificate request was made from the machine (VM) I was trying to install the certficate to.

The origin of this problem was that someone on the IT department restored a previous backup of this VM, so the certificate's private key wasn't available.

I regenerated the private key using the following tutorial:

http://www.entrust.net/knowledge-base/technote.cfm?tn=7905

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if there is an intermediate authority certificate which needs installing? Go to your SSL providers website, they will usually provide them there, if this is the problem.

Either way, the error is being generated because IIS cannot verify the integrity of the root certificate authority